# Sails js ignore id in create/update requests

Tags: sails.js

Sails enables passing an id property when creating an entity,

i want to ignore the id value the user sent and just set my own with autoincrement

how can i do this?

Comment: do you mean the id of the record ? what do you mean by the value sent by the user ? show some code if possible.

Comment: @HamzaFatmi when you generate an api using sails it has default crud routes, and what i noticed is that you can send an id to the create post method and sails will set the id, this is bad behavior, i want the id to be auto generated

Comment: why you don't add your own `create` route, to override the default one so you can have the expected behavior ?

Comment: @HamzaFatmi because, if there is some functionality in sails that allows  me to do this i would like to use it, and i dont want to override the create function for every entity, that seems dumb to me, this is basic functionality, i simply want to ignore/guard certain properties, for example i wouldn't want to enable updating a user`s password

Answer (score 0):

You can do this per model in sails [lifecycle callbacks](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks). For example, if you have a `User` model, in `models/User.js` you can add:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        // etc
    },

    beforeCreate: function(attribs, cb) {
        // modify the attributes as needed here
        delete attribs.id;
        cb();
    }
}
```

There are similar callbacks for `beforeUpdate`, etc.  Unfortunately, this would have to be done in every model you want to affect.

One way to remove ids from every blueprint `create` request would be to use a policy. [Create a policy](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies) that strips `id` from `req.body`, then apply that policy to the route `POST /:model` (there's an example of applying policies directly to routes [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes)). If you do this, be careful as this could mask other `POST` routes you are trying to use.